# Can I use a (undeveloped) trademark or business name as part of a longer name for my business?

Tags: trademark

There is a Website (for the sake of discussion) called www.maxgrav.com.  The site has no content except a landing page (with no discussion on what the product is), which hasn't changed since 2011.  The MaxGrav logo shows to be Trademarked (R) (though a search in USPTO showed no results).  And supposedly there is a MaxGrav Inc. company name.

If I wanted to created a company called MaxGrav Solutions (www.maxgavsolutions.com) which is in no way modeled or named after this company, and the name was something I came up with before searching to see if a similar name was in use, and this name is available in my state...

**Am I in an way infringing upon their trademark or business name etc?**  I'm thinking since the company has no real presence, and a search of MaxGrav doesn't show anything related to their site until the 3rd page of the search results, that no one could say that I am infringing upon anything?  Especially if I grow my company and show an association of MaxGrav Solutions to MY company.